# Animated SVG prevents D3 from transitioning `top` style of separate divs in iOS only

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg, d3.js

My code works properly on Mac (Mavericks) Chrome, Safari, and Firefox, but if fails on iOS7 Chrome and Safari.

On the desktop versions, an SVG with a image-pattern background fills the window and scrolls downward indefinitely, while D3 adds divs to the DOM and transitions their `top` positions to the window's bottom on a `setInterval`.

The animation of the falling blue div fails to occur on mobile.

**If the SVG's `display` is set to `none` or its `visibility` is set to `hidden`, the falling divs transition correctly on iOS.**

**If the SVG `rect` `animateTransform` `repeatCount` is set to a number (rather than `indefinite`), the falling divs transition correctly in iOS.**

**If the I remove `transition` from the D3 selection-styling line, the falling div appears at the bottom of the window in iOS rather than sticking to the top.**

If I connect my mobile device to my Mac and run Safari Dev Tools, I see that the setting of the `top` property on my `div.single` elements altogether fails to occur when the `svg` is displayed.

`top` is added to each `div.single` when `app.parallaxField.style.display = 'none'`:

[image: <code>top</code> is set on each <code>div.single</code>]

`top` is not added to each `div.single` when `app.parallaxField.style.display = 'inline'`:

[image: <code>top</code> is not set on any <code>div.single</code>]

Playing with `z-index` and alternate `display` or `position` options doesn't seem to help.

Any ideas on why one svg's animation would affect D3's transition of the `top` property on separate divs? Thanks!

JS:

```
var app = {};

var drop = function() {

  var numCols = Math.floor(app.windowW / app.singleW) + 1;
  var col = Math.floor(Math.random() * numCols);
  var positionX = (col * app.singleW - app.singleW / 8) - app.singleW / 2;
  var endPositionY = app.windowH - app.singleH;

  var single = d3.select('#singles').append('div');
  single.attr('class', 'single').style({ left: positionX + 'px' });

  // Removing `transition` from the D3 styling makes the blue box appears at bottom of the window in iOS, rather than sticking to the top:
  single.transition().style({ top: endPositionY + 'px' });
  // single.style({ top: endPositionY + 'px' });

};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  app.parallaxField = document.getElementById('parallax-field');

  // Toggling either `display` or `visibility of SVG fixes the falling blue div in iOS:
  // app.parallaxField.style.display = 'none';
  // app.parallaxField.style.visibility = 'hidden';

  app.windowW = window.innerWidth;
  app.windowH = window.innerHeight;
  app.singleW = 128;
  app.singleH = 156;

  window.setInterval(drop, 1000);

});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">

  <svg id="parallax-field" width="100%" height="100%">

    <defs>
      <pattern id="pattern1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="200" width="200">
        <image x="-40" y="-40" height="200" width="200" xlink:href="path/to/image"></image>
      </pattern>
    </defs>

    <rect id="parallax1" width="100%" height="125%" fill="url(#pattern1)">
      <animateTransform
        attributeName="transform"
        type="translate"
        from="0 -100"
        to="0 100"
        dur="3750ms"
        repeatCount="indefinite"
      />
      <!-- Changing above `repeatCount` to a number fixes the dropping blue divs after a short delay. -->
    </rect>

  </svg>

  <div id="singles"></div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  background-color: black;
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0; 
  top: 0; 
}
.single {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 156px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 128px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I solved it by switching from D3 to jQuery, and by switching from animating the foreground divs' `top` values to animating their `margin-top` values instead.

So rather than this (doesn't work with two animating patterned SVGs behind it):

```
var single = d3
  .select('#singles')
  .append('div')
  .attr('class', 'single')
  .style({ left: positionX + 'px' })
  .transition()
  .duration(app.msPerBeat / 2)
  .style({ top: endPositionY + 'px' });
```

This code instead does the job:

```
var single = document.createElement('div');
single.setAttribute('class', 'single');
single.style.left = positionX + 'px';
app.singles.appendChild(single);
$('.single').last().animate({ marginTop: endPositionY + 'px' }, app.msPerBeat / 2);
```